# Get the week as full dates from moment?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, weekday

I am looking to get an entire week as full dates ie:

`Sun Sep 18 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500
Mon Sep 19 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500
Tue Sep 20 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500
Wed Sep 21 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500
Thu Sep 22 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500
Fri Sep 23 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500
Sat Sep 24 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500`

Im building an infinite scroll calendar and I need only one week at a time based on `moment().startOf('week').toString()` or whichever method is best...

`moment.weekdays()` gets me part of the way there, but if I could get something like `moment.weekdays().robust()` that would be ideal...  As always and direction is welcomed and appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I came up with this solution, which works for now...

`const start = moment().startOf('week').weekday(0)
    const week = [...Array(7)].map((_, i) => {
      return start.add('d', 1).format('MMMM Do YYYY')
    })`

returns:

`//[ 'September 19th 2016',
    // 'September 20th 2016',
    // 'September 21st 2016',
    // 'September 22nd 2016',
    // 'September 23rd 2016',
    // 'September 24th 2016',
    // 'September 25th 2016' ]`

also:

`const start = moment().startOf('week').weekday(-1)
    const layout = [...Array(7)].map((_, i) => {
      return start.add('d', 1).utc().toString()
    })`

for UTC formatting starting with Sunday...